# HTML-to-RTF document conversion, preserving classes as styles

Tags: html, converters, rtf

I need a *HTML2RTF* tool,  that is, a software that converts HTML format to RTF format... But not "any convertion": I need to preserve the HTML `class` attributes (ex. of paragraphs) as MS-Word "styles".

My first option was some terminal command of LibreOffice, like

```
libreoffice --convert-to
```

because LibreWriter have the bigger community and suppose the best software convertion... But disappointed because not preserve class attributes as styles, even when testing as user in the graphical interface.

I need a Linux solution (also *abiword* not solved)... Or, last option, a webservice to easy plug in a intranet's Windows server.

---

**Input sample:**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>sample1 doc</title>
   <!-- no style need, but can be declarated with anything, don't matter -->
   <style type="text/css">
     .myStyle1 {color: #F00;}  .myStyle2 {color: #880;}
     .a {color: #00F;} .b {color: #088;}
   </style>
</head>
<body><!-- important to preserve class names -->
  <p class="myStyle1">Hello in <i>style#1</i>. 
     <span class="a">SPAN S1</span>.</p>
  <p class="myStyle2">... Hello in style#2...</p>
  <p class="myStyle1">Bye <span class="b">S2</span>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In MS-Word this sample is imported and looks ok, with styles where was classes.
In LibreOffice (and `libreoffice` terminal tools) not.

**So, there are another tool for LibreOffice?  There are a tool for Linux?**

PS: last possibility, if none for Linux, a *webservice* for Windows and MS-Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in Libreoffice 4.3.3.2. Just opened the HTML file you provided and I can see styles named Text.Body.myStyle1 and myStyle2.

[image: HTML styles in Libreoffice]

---

Clues, for Debian Stable  and UBUNTU LTS 64bits... See [this How-To](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-libreoffice-4-3-3-on-ubuntu-debian-and-derivative-systems/). Basic steps:

```sh
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice*
wget http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.3.3/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.3.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
tar -xzvf LibreOffice_4.3.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice_4.3.3*_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

After v4.3.3, need also to install:

```
 sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```

then, the cited command:

```
 libreoffice --headless -convert-to rtf libreTeste.html
```